# Placing a label behind a tableView when there are no rows in the table

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm looking at the Alarm Clock app on the iPhone and I see that when they are using custom graphics for their UITableViewCells for the gray gradient, and when there are no cells in the table, there is a background that looks like similar to the grouped table view cells background with a label that says No Alarms.

How can I achieve this effect?  Currently in my view controller, I have the viewController's view, a label for "No Alarms" and the tableView.  When I have zero alarms in the table, I just show the label, and hide the table, and vice vsa when there are alarms.  The problem I'm getting is the graphics.

As a test, if I change the background color of the table to bright orange, that orange shines through to my tableViewCells.  The tableViewCells and the tableView are both set to the default white, not clearColor and yet the viewController's view shines through.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Set the  View's background to "Group Table Background color" using XIB file. We can set the same background image to our view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the "No Alarms" label is the topmost subview in your view's hierarchy. If it is, then you shouldn't have to worry about hiding your table view and won't have to deal with the problems you are having with the orange/white backgrounds.

Programatically, adding a label to the top level view would look something like:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"No Alarms";
// set the properties, autoresizing, etc...
[label sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

The last line is what actually adds the label to your view.  If you want to have the label centered in the view you want to maybe use `initWithFrame:` as opposed to just init that way you can have it in the center of the view.

Another option (if you are using a NIB or storyboards) is to just create a "No Alarms" label and make sure it is the topmost subview in the view's subview hierarchy on the IB item explorer (I think that's what it's called at least - either way I'm referring to the flyout menu where you can select the objects in your view).  Then just hide and unhide the label when your program logic says there are and aren't alarms.  This is the way I'd probably do it...